# Concrete5 5.7: Passing variable from Controller to View

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7

So I have made a dashboard Single Page under:

```php
/application/single_pages/dashboard/newsletter.php
```

and a

```php
/application/single_pages/dashboard/view.php
```

The Controller is under:

```php
/Concrete/controllers/single_pages/dashboard/newsletter.php
```

---

The Controller looks like:

```php
<?php
namespace Concrete\Controller\SinglePage\Dashboard;
use Concrete\Core\Multilingual\Page\PageList;
use \Concrete\Core\Page\Controller\DashboardPageController;
class Newsletter extends DashboardPageController {
    public function view() {
        $testVar = array(
            'one' => 'some',
            'two' => 'value',
            'three' => 'foo',
            'four' => 'bar'
        );
        $this->set('test', $testVar);
    }
}
```

The `/application/single_pages/dashboard/newsletter.php` looks like:

```php
<?php defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
echo 'something';
print_r($test);
```

The `/application/single_pages/dashboard/view.php` looks like:

```php
<?php defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

The local variable `$test` doesn't show up in the view.

The `echo 'something';` is showing, so basically the page is up and running.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a path & namespace issue:

The path for the controller must be:

```php
/application/controllers/single_page/dashboard/newsletter.php
```

instead of:

```php
/concrete/controllers/single_pages/dashboard/newsletter.php
```

For the controller path its singular `single_page` but for the Single Page itself its plural `single_pages`

---

When extending from the core, we need to adapt the namespace to:

```php
Application\Controller\SinglePage\Dashboard
```

instead of:

```php
Concrete\Controller\SinglePage\Dashboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `singlepage` before the controller is in place will cause it to be detached from the controller without warning, try removing it and re-adding it.

Comment: Nope. Even after removing everything and adding the controller first, then the single page